# Shift-Tab not working anymore

Tags: windows

I recently installed Visual Studio 14.

I'm not sure but since then, the Shift-Tab function does not work.
I cannot use shift-tab to unintended, but I cannot even use Alt-Shift-Tab to go in reverse direction that Alt-Tab, but Alt-Tab works. This problem is on every program and even explorer.exe. I can't go backward in focus but I can go forward in focus with Tab, and the Shift button also works.

I don't know what to do I'm about to loose it everything refers me to problem on a single program but for me my whole OS is 'infected'.
I am on Windows 7 64bit.

What I need is an actual method on how to test where does the problem may come from.

Thank you,
rt-2

Comment: This may be a silly question but are you sure you haven't turned on [Sticky Keys](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_xp-hardware/shift-keys-not-working/0e6e87de-1741-492a-9c08-7d7282604db6?auth=1) somehow?

Comment: @neophlegm There is no silly questions! No I have them ALL deactivated. Thank you for your reply. I'm actually gonna need a method on how to test where is the problem....